# upgrade to vue3 Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler/package.json'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

As written in this manual https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/vue-3-migration-build/
I'm updated package.json added vue.config.js and ran yarn install command, and see this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler/package.json'
Require stack:
- /myproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js
- /myproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /myproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at /myproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js:73:32
    at /myproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:242:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (/myproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:242:26)
    at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (/myproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:246:48)
    at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (/myproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/PluginAPI.js:138:25)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

i tried changing compiler versions but it doesn't help
how to fix it ?
thanks in advance

Comment: install vue-template-compiler manually, running `npm i -g vue-template-compiler` fixes the problem.  reference: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2109#issuecomment-411384824

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't help
`npm i -g vue-template-compiler  
+ vue-template-compiler@2.6.14  
updated 1 package in 1.135s  

my@pc:~/myproject$ npm run serve  
> myproject$@0.1.0 serve /projects/myproject$  
> vue-cli-service serve  
  
 INFO  Starting development server...  
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler/package.json'`

Comment: try removing node_modules folder and re installing with `npm i`

Comment: @Cameron, vue-template-compiler is for vue 2, so not sure how it would help here for vue3. I'm getting the same error and installing it globally didn't help for me either.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add `@vue/compiler-sfc`? See installation step 2 here: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html#installation

Comment: add to this, `vue-template-compiler` was a dependency of the previous version of `vue-svg-loader`, so upgrading that was necessary too